# How long Local Storage Item will be saved in a Disk

Tags: html, sqlite, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have few doubts regarding localStorage and sqlite database. I am developing a Google Chrome extension. The main functionality is It will allow to load text files and can be used for later purposes. These are my doubts

1. Is storing data in localStorage reliable?
2. Why should I use sqlite database over localStorage?
3. How long items stored in Sqlite and localStorage exists in browser?

Answer (score 1):

1. As everything, that is stored client-side (e.g. cookies) localStorage is not 100% reliable.
2. Web SQL Database supports SQL standard (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.), on the other hand localStorage is simple key-value storage, and in current implementations value must be string.
3. Until user delete it manually or by reinstalling browser/OS.